# JPA required getters and setters for the entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to the Spring ecosystem and I wonder if the @Entity class should **always** have getters and setters and that all the properties should be private? Is it correct that the JPA(or Hibernate) will require those methods (getters/setters) to fetch the values or set them in the database ?

Comment: This is an opinion, as there is no requirement anywhere but using Fields outside of the class limits providers and what they can do to instrument the class for lazy access. You can use it, but as when disregarding any best practice, you should know what you are doing and have a good reason for it.

Comment: All the fields should be private, not the properties

Answer (score 3):

From the [JakartaEE JPA 3.0 specification, §2.2.: Persistent Fields and Properties](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#persistent-fields-and-properties):

> #### 2.2. Persistent Fields and Properties
>
> The persistent state of an entity is accessed by the persistence provider runtime<sup>[[1]](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#_footnotedef_1)</sup> either via JavaBeans style property accessors (“property access”) or via instance variables (“field access”). ...
>
> ...
>
> The instance variables of a class must be private, protected, or package visibility independent of whether field access or property access is used. When property access is used, the property accessor methods must be public or protected.
>
> ....

This means that accessors are not strictly required, but highly recommended. The alternative (field access) is regarded as a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use @entity, it also helps for others when they read your code, it documents it, you use private and @Data annotation from Lombok (to auto generate Getter/setter)